# Issue running Web app in eclipse with tomcat 8 on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Hello

I'm facing the following problem that I'm going to try to explain to you to see if someone have experience and could help me to get this done:

I have install on my MAC OS X Capitan the Eclipse IDE MARS, I download the Tomcat 8 and put in my Document folder.

I created a Dynamic Web Application and I build it and everything compiles without any errors, after that I create a server and did the reference to Tomcat folder in this way:.

[Web Dynamic Project run with tomcat](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html)

When I started the tomcat and perfectly fine started and when I want to run the application nothing happen, I opened the browser and try to access to the jsp file but doesn't happen, not show any error but neither show the web page(only with hello world)

Any idea I'm pretty new with eclipse so please I need your consideration on this.

Comment: It is possible that your server doesn't find the path to your web application - so it doesn't display anything. Check in your tomcat logs (it will be in your tomcat installation directory/logs/catalina.out) if there is any activity when you open your web site in a browser. You might want to try copy-pasting your .war file into your tomcat dir/webapps folder.

Comment: Thank you very much @TR1, I will do what you are suggesting me, and I let you know.

Comment: Just go to your project and ctrl click and do run - run as server

Comment: Thanks @Dudi but when I do your suggestion the run as server is deactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank you all for your comments, it help me a lot.

I solve the problem in this way:

1. Deleted the previous project.
2. Create a Tomcat server again, but in this time I created selecting the option: Create a new local server (I think this was the main issue, because I didn't installed the tomcat so I needed that Eclipse install the Tomcat).
3. I created again the project using the default run environment.
4. I select run as server.

And is running the project.

Thanks again to all.